# how to fetch Has_many relationship values on RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

Can any one please help to how to fetch the values of attributes from the **has_many** Relationship on rails

For example
company is one relation and has many email

```
company --> email
```

i need to fetch email_address from those company.email

How can i do that?

```
company.email.email_address
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@company = Company.find(1)
@company.emails.collect(&:email_address)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

@company = Email_address.find(:all,params[:email_id],
:include => #:user,
:conditions => "email_id=#{params[:email_id].to_i} AND published=true")

Answer (score 1):

```
email_addresses = Company.all.map(&:emails).map(&:email_addresses)
```